after Ubuntu use, chkdsk gets Deleting extended attribute set
An external harddrive was mounted on Ubuntu 24.04.  Later, while on a Windows (pre win10) system, a chkdsk was run.  The harddrive is formated NTFS. The chkdsk responded with lots of
Deleting extended attribute set
due to the presence of reparse point in file 

Why is this happening and, should I be concerned?

eh you need to ask windows users. I would say: yes very bad.

Windows (tm) intentionally does not understand any Linux filesystem, and treats them as junque.
